# Changing label type in Arch Linux cfdisk

Tags: arch-linux, partition, disk, cfdisk

I'm trying to install Arch Linux on a disk which was previously partitioned. The Disklabel type is automatically set to *gpt*. I need to change it to *dos*. How can I do it?

Comment: are you sure you *need* to change it to a DOS label? there's several advantages to using GPT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never actually used `cfdisk`, but I can tell you how to do it with `fdisk`.

1. Run `fdisk -l`
2. You should get all of your storage devices.
3. Find the one you want to partition.
4. It should be something like `/dev/nvme0n1` or `/dev/sda` but your knowledge may vary.
5. Once you find it run `fdisk <name of drive>`. E.x. `/fdsik /dev/sda`
6. You should now see something like this

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.35.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.

Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help):
```

Typing `m` reveals:

> **o**   create a new empty DOS partition table

**Notes:**

- Know that changing the labels will delete everything.
- Don't forget to run **w** before exiting to write table to disk.
- Check the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Partition_the_disks) for more information.